# TensorFlow: What is the effect of calling tf.random.set_seed() twice, where the second function call is passed a hard-coded value?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I'm using someone else's code base and in one spot (early on in execution), the tensorflow seed is set via `tf.random.set_seed(seed)`, where `seed` is provided via command line argument. But then a bit later in execution, they set it again with `tf.random.set_seed(0)`.

What is the effect of setting the seed a second time with a hard-coded constant?

Does it mean that everything which happens after the second call will be identical, even for different `seed`s?

Answer (score 0):

I realized checking myself yields a faster answer than waiting. For anyone else wondering, the answer is yes.

```
import tensorflow as tf


for seed in range(3):
    print(seed)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    print(tf.random.uniform(shape=(3, 2)))
    tf.random.set_seed(0)
    print(tf.random.uniform(shape=(3, 2)))
```

The second tensor will always be the same.